# Does Grid.Children.Clear() really remove all controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

Edit:
Simple answer: Yes, it does. I found the error, which was, that another event handler was added, everytime the `Combobox_SelectionChanged` was fired. Hence, the collection looked fine, but the `Items_CollectionChanged` was fired multiple times. Once this was fixed, everything worked fine.
End Edit.

I've got a page with a combobox and a grid. The grid fills dynamically, when the selection in the combobox changes. I'm now observing a strange thing. When I select a value for the second time in the combobox, the childitems in the grid appear twice. I've checked the underlying collections, which look fine (i.e. only one record per item). When I jump out of the combobox_SelectionChanged method, after the `Grid.Children.Clear()` command, the screen looks fine, i.e. empty.

My guess is, that `Grid.Children.Clear()` only removes the controls from the visual tree, but the actual controls are still hanging around. Any Ideas?

```
private void combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    grItems.Children.Clear();
    grItemsColumnDefinitions.Clear();
    grItemsColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(200) });
}

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
             grItems.Children.Add(new ChildItemControl(e.NewItems[0]));
        }

    }
```

Edit: The whole thing is supposed to look like this (fictional - but hopefully understandable - example)
[image]

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you can't use bindings for this instead of adding things to the grid manually?

Comment: Well, one reason is my lack of xaml skills;) But the other one is, that the structure itself is quite complex as well as the way it should be displayed.  There a few more vertical and horizontal layers involed (days, buyers, departments, aso) Hence I found it easier to handle if the controls are added in codebehind.

Comment: You shouldn't think that the "structure" of the data is too complex for databinding.  The more complex the data, the more you should rely on databinding, as you are bound to make more mistakes in your backend logic than you are to make in your binding templates.  Take a look at the MVVM sample in the Documentation section of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wpf/2134/simple-mvvm-example#t=201607261427091123224

Comment: Agree with @joe_coolish here, databinding is almost always the way to go if you aren't designing your own UI controls

Comment: I've added a simplyfied structure of the grid. I'm not opposed to use databinding (actually I would prefer to), however, I've yet failed to find a good example on how to create a "pivot" table in wpf.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the built in Databinding for WPF.  You could use something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grItems" ItemsSource="{Binding comboboxItems}" />
```

Then, when you update `comboboxItems` your grid will automatically update too!
Here is a great article on Databinding with the DataGrid control:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

For more information about Databinding in general, here is a good article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx